# Why is the "last seen" field shown in own profile, and can it be removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Is there any reason to see the "last seen" field on the [current user's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) (i.e. your own) profile page?

> [image: Last seen this week]

Can this ever be anything other than "Last seen this week"?
Maybe it should be removed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Last seen" has always been shown on one's own profile page (though I don't know why), except for the period of time during which it was removed from all profile pages entirely. It was readded with less granularity (except for non-mods), and I think the smallest/most recent level it shows it "Last seen this week".

Comment: Are you just asking why, or would also like to remove it? (In that case, add [tag:feature-request].)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 it was there, but removed during edit by another user.

Comment: Yeah well title wasn't a feature request, I "fixed" it. :)

Comment: @zcoop98 how exactly is this about design?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I felt that including or not including a certain field on the profile page was part of the _design_ of said page. I thought it was a natural choice for a question regarding why a certain page feature exists and whether it should be removed or not.

Comment: @zcoop98 no, design tag is for the layout, or CSS, e.g. if the request was to move the field to different location, or change the font, etc. When it's about adding or removing fields, design doesn't fit - otherwise it would be required in *all* feature requests. After all, they all asking to change *something*. :)

Comment: I agree with this, *unless* they're going to be more specific about it.  If not, there's no reason to show it on your own profile page

Comment: Why would you not want to know what's being shown to other people?

Comment: @Makyen In general, I do.  I already know when *I* was last seen (and much more accurately as well) by looking at my clock, so I see no reason to have a less-specific metric on your profile page.